# MongoID : match multiple elements in array and update all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I use MongoID and PostgreSQL on Rails 4 and I have a notification system.

Each user has one notification document. I would like to be able to *mark all as read* in a controller.
Here is my notification schema :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53e360156d6163513e000000"),
  "unread_counter" : 1,
  "user_id" : 1,
  "rows" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("53e369166d61635328000000"),
      "readed" : false,
      "created_at" : ISODate("2014-08-07T11:55:02.936Z"),
      "author" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53e369166d61635328010000"),
        "username" : "edouard",
        "user_id" : 6
      },
      "subject" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53e369166d61635328020000"),
        "type" : "follower"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that `elem_match` just match one element in `rows` array.

```
Notification.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
.elem_match(rows: { readed: false })
.update_all("$set" => {"rows.$.readed" => true })
```

I have been inspired by this post : [mongoid update elements within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346287/mongoid-update-elements-within-array)

How can I match all `"readed" : false` row elements and then update them to `true` ?

Comment: See (non-MongoID) dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb

Comment: Another approach maybe ?

Comment: I change my schema. Now I have a document for each notification. It's more simple that way but I don't know about performance.